# can i transfer money from stripe to customer card?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, google-api-nodejs-client

i am using stripe API for payment getaway and i get charges from customer using card details ,
now i want to transfer some money to the customer who have card detail .

i have try one transfer that can done using bank detail but i don't want to transfer money using bank detail because all customer will charge using card detail and i want to transfer money to that same customer who charge to stripe and stripe will charge some amount to the same customer .

simple i can say i want to transfer money from stripe to customer and that customer have customer id and card id.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgDy4.png)

Comment: Your question is very broad. Give some details. What have you already write?

Comment: i am creating payment getaway using stripe API now i want that any customer charge money from that money transfer some money to some other customer 's card.

Comment: @Alex Have you found a solution? I'm in the same situation atm

Answer (score -3, accepted):

yes, you can transfer amount to customer card using Stripe transfer. Stripe will charge few percentage of amount and do it for you.
You can read more about it here

[transfer api](https://stripe.com/docs/api#transfers)

[Stripe transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/special-case-transfers)

Comment: i have try this stripe.transfers.create(
  {
    amount: 1000,
    currency: 'usd',
    destination: {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}
  }
);

Comment: but i don't want to use bank account i want to transfer money to my customer's card .

Comment: you are using connected stripe request. In this way you have to connect customer to your stripe account

Comment: i have done it too. what is process is , first customer pay with card detail . than i want to transfer that money to other customer who is connected with stripe . but main problem is all work must be done with card detail not with bank account .